# Using Type Script w/ ASP.Net Core build errors from .xproj file

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, typescript

I'm working on a new ASP.Net Core project, and I've [followed a blog post](http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/08/08/setup-angular2-typescript-aspnetcore-in-visualstudio.html) on setting it up with Angular 2 and Type Script. As soon as I add a Type Script file to my project, I'm given the following build errors from my xproj file.

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong? This is my project.json, package.json and systemjs.config.js along with the sole Type Script file in the project.

#### project.json

```
{
  "title": "Manage Care Web",
  "userSecretsId": "ManageCare-Apps-Web-c23d27a4-eb88-4b18-9b77-2a93f3b15119",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha2-final",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Security.AspIdentity": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "Security.Jwt": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "DataAccess.Abstraction": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "DataAccess.SqlServer": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Domain.Provider": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Domain.Security": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Security.Abstractions": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Services.Abstractions": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Services.Provider": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win7-x64": {}
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "managecare",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.3",
    "typings": "1.4.0"
  }
}
```

#### systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'libs/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './ClientApp.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

#### typings.config

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

#### ClientApp.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// import { AppModule } from './App/app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

// platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

What am I doing wrong with this setup? I've never used Type Script before, but my impression was that this just worked out of the box in Visual Studio. Is there more that I have to do than what was described in the blog post I linked to?

### update

I installed the typings npm package as recommended by an anonymous user, but when I run `typings install dt~core-js --global --save` I get the following exception.

> C:\Users\Sully\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\typings-core\node_modules\strip-bom\index.js:2
>   module.exports = x => {
>                     ^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at Object. >
>
> (C:\Users\Sully\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\typings-core\dist\utils\fs.js:5:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)

Answer (score 1):

Please install nuget package : angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
    https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

Add the below in 'typings.json' file, it is working fine for me:

```
        {
          "globalDependencies": {
            "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
            "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160831021119"
          }
        }
```

Below is my 'tsconfig.json' file:

```
            {
              "compilerOptions": {
                "noImplicitAny": true,
                "noEmitOnError": true,
                "removeComments": false,
                "sourceMap": true,
                "target": "es5",
                "module": "commonjs",
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "skipLibCheck": false,
                "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
                "types": ["node","js-base64"]
              },
              "exclude": [
                "node_modules",
                "wwwroot"
              ],
              "compileOnSave": false
            }
```

Also try to run the below if not done already:

```
     typings install dt~core-js --global --save
```

Comment: I had that one as well, it didn't help.

Comment: Did you add typings.json file to your project? Also, did you manually run npm install? as sometimes it does not restore packages on save.

Comment: I have a typings.config file mentioned by Angular. How do I determine what goes into a typings.json file?

Comment: When I run the `typings` command I get an exception, I updated my OP with the exception details. I also updated my tsconfig.json to match yours and it didn't fix the issue. My typings package was installed both locally, and I installed it globally. Didn't seem to make a difference.